# Как спарсить только определённый тег (с помощью simple html dom)?

Tags: php, веб-скрейпинг

Приветствую. Использую Simple HTML DOM для парсинга товаров интернет-магазина. Параметр "вес товара" лежит в этом куске:

```
            <div id="AddnInfo">
            <p>
                <p><label>&ldquo;R&rdquo;Web#:</label> <span class="value">399014</span></p>
                <p><label>SKU:</label> <span class="value">0279D033</span></p> 
                <p><label>Manufacturer #:</label> B5529</p>
                <p><label>Product Weight:</label>1.5&nbsp;pounds</p>
                <p><label>Product Dimensions (in inches):</label>8.5 x 7.9 x 2.3</p>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Причём, как до нужной цифры, так и после неё может быть совершенно любое количество < p > ... < / p >, т. е. её место в вышеуказанном списке непостоянно.
Вопрос - по какому принципу можно выдернуть из этого кода Product Weight?

Comment: по прямому, перебрать все p и посмотреть есть ли там нужный label

Comment: @teran посмотреть есть ли нужный лейбл - а как? вот в этом у меня и загвоздка)) цифра-то не внутри < label > .. < / label > лежит, а вне его

Comment: Можно попробовать регуляркой по содержимому AddInfo  `/(\d|\.)+(&nbsp;)+pounds/`

Comment: вернее, проще просто  найти лэйблы, узнать у которого нужный текст и взят родительский `p`

Comment: @br3t с помощью данной регулярки в моём примере вместо 1.5 выводится просто 1, я к сожалению в регулярках не силён, в чём может быть дело?

Comment: Пробуйте `/([.\d]+)(&nbsp;)+pounds/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вас следует найти исходный родительской блок `#AddnInfo` и список всех дочерних элементов `label`. Далее сравнить содержимое текста этих меток на предмет соответствия `Product weight:`. Для найденной нужной метки взять родительский элемент и получить его текстовый контент:

```
define("PRODUCT_WEIGHT", 'Product Weight:');
$html = str_get_html($txt);

$labels = $html->find("#AddnInfo label");
foreach($labels as $l){
    if($l->innertext === PRODUCT_WEIGHT){
        $weight = (string)$l->parent()->find('text', 1)
        break;
    }
}

print_r([$weight, html_entity_decode($weight)]);
```

`$weight` будет содержать значение `1.5&nbsp;pounds`. С помощью [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php) можно преобразовать `&nbsp`, но преобразуется оно не в обычный ASCII пробел (`32`), а в `160`й (`0xA0`), и поэтому не обрезается с помощью `trim()`.

---

Если вам далее потребуется вытащить только численное значение, то вы можете либо просто удалить подстроку `&nbsp; pounds`, либо, если допустить, что там не всегда `pounds` и т.п. воспользоваться соответствующим регулярным выражением:

```
preg_match("/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/", $weight, $matches);
```

тогда в `$matches[0]` окажется зачение `1.5`